# Site slow + high cpu usage without requests

Tags: python, linux, django, performance, apache

I have a website running at VPS with Apache-FastCGI-Django stack. Sometimes it becomes very slow, taking minute to open a page or even throwing 503.

I checked top command and got: http://pastebin.com/8qdCPUQk. So we have some load, there is some free RAM and a several processes eating CPU.

I looked into apache log files and checked that there are very few requests there.

After it checked one of the python processes with strace and it mostly contains

```
futex(0x16aab90, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
```

and sometimes

```
futex(0x16aab90, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Could you advice something on it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - because of the bug process gets into infinite loop after one of the requests.